# Correct way of calculating probability given a condition

Tags: python, pandas, probability

I have some data which shows how many orders were made by a certain customer group that bought a certain product type:

[image]

And the same format but showing how many refunds were made:

[image]

I am trying to answer a question:

*What is the probability that an order is made by a customer in the group [A - B] and is refunded?*

My approach was:

```
being_in_group = df_final[df_final.customer_group.isin(['A','B'])]\
                                                 .groupby('customer_group')\
                                                 .agg({'order_id': 'count'}).sum(axis = 0)

all_orders = df_final.groupby('customer_group').agg({'order_id': 'count'})\
                                               .sum(axis = 0)

p_being_in_group = round(being_in_group / all_orders, 5)

being_refunded = df_final[(df_final.refund == True) & (df_final.customer_group.isin(['A','B']))]\
                         .groupby('customer_group')\
                         .agg({'order_id': 'count'})\
                         .sum(axis = 0)                        
# or taking all customer groups
being_refunded_all = df_final[(df_final.refund == True)]\
                         .groupby('customer_group')\
                         .agg({'order_id': 'count'})\
                         .sum(axis = 0)

p_being_refunded = round(being_refunded / all_orders, 5)
p_being_refunded_all = round(being_refunded_all / all_orders, 5)

p_final_1 = p_being_in_group * p_being_refunded * 100
p_final_2 = p_being_in_group * p_being_refunded_all * 100
```

I am wondering if that is the correct approach - calculating the probability of an order being made by the group `A & B` and then checking the refunded orders - should I check the refunded orders in all of the data or only in the data where `customer_group` is `A & B`?

Comment: Does `[A - B]` mean customer in either group A or group B?

Comment: Yes, customer can be in group `A or B`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so first of all bit of technicality - with a given sample dataset you can calculate ***proportions***, not *probability*. You can assume that probability will be relatively close, but that's gonna be just that, an assumption. More about the difference [here](https://www.statology.org/probability-vs-proportion/).

In order to find out this proportion, you have to indentify 2 sets of observations - total observation space that interests us - in your case, we don't make any assumptions, so we take whole observation space. That is, all the orders. You sum every number in all_orders and that will be our total number of events.

Second set we have to find out is the one that matches **all the conditions**.

We have 2 conditions:

- customer is in group A or B
- order is refunded

Second one is easy - if an order is refunded, it is counted in the second table.
So now we just have to count the ones in there that satisfy first condition (13).

Divide 13 by whatever is the sum of all_orders, and you get your total *proportion* of an order being refunded and in the group A or B.

Comment: Wouldn't I need to then divide `13` by the orders inside the group `A / B`? and then multiply it by the probability of `p_being_in_group `?

Comment: Why do you think that?

Comment: Firstly calculate the probabilty of an order being in group A or B AND probability of order being refunded, since we have AND we should multiply the probabilities.

The question I have is which probability of order being refunded to use : all refunds / all orders or refunds in A&B / orders in A&B?

Comment: If you want to use the `P(A and B) = P(A) * P(B)` formula, then you treat each event **independantly**. Let's identify what is our A and B - `order is made by a customer in the group [A - B] (A)` and `[order] is refunded (B)`. As we can see, (B) has nothing to do with groups A and B, so it makes it clear that your 2nd and 3rd option are not valid. P(B) will be `all refunds / all orders`. When using that formula, you don't use the 13 I came up with in my answer, because it has already taken both (A) and (B) into account.